# How to "addTiles" on top of "addPolygons" in R's Leaflet?

Tags: r, leaflet

How do you set the layer order in R's leaflet package so that tiles show up on top of polygons filled with color?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
require(leaflet)
require(acs)
require(tigris)
require(rgdal)
census.income.end.year = 2015
county = 17
nd.counties=acs.fetch(geography=geo.make(state="ND", county=county), 
                      table.number="B01003", endyear = 2015)

tracts <- tigris::tracts(state = 'ND', county = county, cb=FALSE, year = 2015)

# create a geographic set to grab tabular data (acs)
geo<-geo.make(state=c("ND"),
              county = county,
              tract="*")

# add in median income
median.income <- acs.fetch(endyear = census.income.end.year, 
                           geography = geo, 
                           variable = c("B19013_001"))
income_df <- data.frame(paste0(as.character(median.income@geography$state), 
                               str_pad(as.character(median.income@geography$county), 3, 'left', '0'), 
                               str_pad(as.character(median.income@geography$tract), 5, 'left', '0')), 
                        median.income@estimate)

rownames(income_df)<-1:nrow(income_df)
names(income_df)<-c("GEOID", "hhincome")
income_merged <- geo_join(tracts, income_df, "GEOID", "GEOID")

income_merged <- spTransform(income_merged, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

qpal <- colorQuantile("plasma", income_df$hhincome, n = 4)

leaflet() %>% 
  setView( -96.7898, 46.8772, zoom=11) %>% 
  addPolygons(data = income_merged, 
              fillColor = qpal(income_merged$hhincome), 
              fillOpacity = 1, 
              weight = 0.3) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Hydda.RoadsAndLabels)
```

Ultimately, I'ld like to do this with addTiles (instead of addProviderTiles as in the above code) using a custom MapBox, but I can't figure out how to make that reproducible for this example... given that you need a key to access custom MapBox tiles (BTW, I've created a custom MapBox tile that should be transparent except for roads and labels, so the underlying polygons should "show thru.")

Here is one way to do add a tile on top of a circle with the non-R version of leaflet: http://jsfiddle.net/dcu9pz2w/, but I don't see how to make that work in my context. I think adding "panes" may be the way to go, but I don't see that functionality in R leaflet. Also, I explored z-index values, but that seemed to be a dead end.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `help(addTiles)` may provide you the solution. Try `addTiles(urlTemplate="http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", attribution='&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>')`

Comment: @kitman0804: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to **order** layers, not just add tiles.

Comment: Unless you find a tile provider that serves vector tiles (separated by content type - e.g. streets, water bodies, POIs, labels, ...) or you have such tiles yourself, what you try to do is not possible. All standard tile servers provide raster image layers (i.e. png images) that are pre-calculated for each zoom level. Hence, you cannot separate individual components from the images.

Comment: @TimSalabim: Thank you for the idea. However, here is an example that seems to do what you say is not possible: http://jsfiddle.net/dcu9pz2w/. The tile provider is OpenStreetMaps and the tiles seem to be in png format. The problem with the example is that I don't know how to make that kind of layering work in R's leaflet.

Comment: The current leaflet implementation doesn't seem to allow setting the `zIndex` or `pane` properly (tiles and images are placed on the tile pane whereas polygons/lines/circles are placed on the overlay pane which has a higher zIndex). I suggest you open an issue on their [github repository](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet). It would be really useful if we could manipulate layer ordering also for overlaying polygon etc on top of raster images.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

R leaflet now includes [`addMapPane`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet/versions/2.0.1/topics/addMapPane) function. The solution to this problem is to first set up pane order and then add tiles/polygons. Reproducible example:

```
library(leaflet)
library(geojsonio)

# get polygon data
# https://github.com/simonepri/geo-maps/blob/master/info/countries-land.md
world <- geojson_read(
  "https://github.com/simonepri/geo-maps/releases/download/v0.6.0/countries-land-10km.geo.json", 
  what = "sp"
)

# generate random values
world@data$value <- runif(nrow(world@data))

# get color palette
color_pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "YlOrRd", domain = NULL)

# get leaflet map
leaflet() %>%
  setView(lat = 50, lng = 15, zoom = 4) %>%
  addMapPane("background_map", zIndex = 410) %>%  # Level 1: bottom
  addMapPane("polygons", zIndex = 420) %>%        # Level 2: middle
  addMapPane("labels", zIndex = 430) %>%          # Level 3: top
  addProviderTiles(
    providers$Esri.WorldTerrain,
    options = pathOptions(pane = "background_map")
  ) %>%
  addPolygons(
    data = world, stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2,
    fillOpacity = 0.6, fillColor = ~color_pal(value),
    options = pathOptions(pane = "polygons")
  ) %>%
  addProviderTiles(
    providers$Stamen.TonerLabels,
    options = pathOptions(pane = "labels")
  )
```

Comment: At first glance, this looks perfect.